# Kernel fails to build Broadcomm dkms modules, how to fix it?

Tags: wireless, kernel, broadcom

My computer is not recognising the wireless network. When I try to activate my drivers I get errors. I tried to solve by:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

but I am getting these errors :

```
Building initial module for 3.8.0-30-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-30-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.20.155.1+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
FATAL: Module wl not found.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-30-generic
```

`lsmod` :

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   17852  2 
rfcomm                 38400  12 
parport_pc             27612  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
uvcvideo               72250  0 
i915                  550344  8 
videobuf2_core         39385  1 uvcvideo
videodev               96131  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
radeon                892298  1 
coretemp               13324  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      12920  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13042  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     36564  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      64649  1 
snd_hda_intel          38819  5 
ttm                    72088  1 radeon
snd_hda_codec         118650  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
kvm_intel             127786  0 
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                85934  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
drm_kms_helper         47749  2 i915,radeon
btusb                  17951  0 
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_rawmidi            25157  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 17329  0 
bluetooth             211435  24 bnep,rfcomm,btusb
kvm                   384557  1 kvm_intel
snd_seq                51593  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
drm                   233935  7 i915,radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
hp_accel               25756  0 
psmouse                82769  0 
snd                    57014  20 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
lis3lv02d              19536  1 hp_accel
mei                    36756  0 
hp_wmi                 17748  0 
intel_ips              17738  0 
serio_raw              13031  0 
sparse_keymap          13658  1 hp_wmi
microcode              18433  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13316  2 i915,radeon
lpc_ich                17048  0 
input_polldev          13648  1 lis3lv02d
soundcore              12600  1 snd
video                  19116  1 i915
snd_page_alloc         18398  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
wmi                    18744  1 hp_wmi
mac_hid                13077  0 
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
ahci                   25631  4 
libahci                26336  1 ahci
r8169                  62532  0
```